# How to combine multiple lines in a single legend entry for a quantity which depends on multiple variables?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

**Goal**

- Calculate two quantities `q1` and `q2`, which both depend on two variables `v1` and `v2`.
- Plot both quantities for a select number of values of variable 1, as function of variable 2.
- For each selected value for variable 1: list the value, as well as the average value for quantities 1 and 2 (+ error margins) in one legend entry

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736920/line-plus-shaded-region-for-error-band-in-matplotlibs-legend), which shows desired output for a single (line + filled area), but could not get it to work with this more extensive problem.

**Question**

The main question is to create the legend as described above. Thanks!

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

def calc_quant1(x,y):
    q1 = x + y
    q1err = np.sqrt(x+y)
    return q1,q1err

def calc_quant2(x,y):
    q2 = x - y
    q2err = np.sqrt((x+y)/2)
    return q2,q2err


# variables
var1 = np.linspace(-6,10,5)
var2 = np.linspace(10,20,21)

# resulting quantities (preallocation)
quant1 = np.zeros((len(var1),len(var2)))
quant2 = np.zeros((len(var1),len(var2)))
quant1err = np.zeros((len(var1),len(var2)))
quant2err = np.zeros((len(var1),len(var2)))
dy_dx = np.zeros(len(var2))

# plot colors
colors = cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,len(var1)))

# reference value
xref = 12

# initialize figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
fig.suptitle('Title')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axvline(x=xref,color='black',linestyle='dashed',label='$x={}$'.format(xref))
    
# compute and plot
for i in np.arange(len(var1)):
    
    # select "measured" voltage
    v1 = var1[i] * np.ones(len(var2))
    v1err = var1err[i] * np.ones(len(var2))
    
    # compute heat flux
    quant1[i,:], quant1err[i,:] = calc_quant1(v1,var2)
    quant2[i,:], quant2err[i,:] = calc_quant2(v1,var2)
    
    # compute gradient near reference point (suboptimal)
    x1 = var2[var2<xref][-1]
    x2 = var2[var2>xref][0]
    y1 = quant2[i][var2<xref][-1]
    y2 = quant2[i][var2>xref][0]
    dy_dx[i] = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    
    # plot results
    label1 = r'$v_{{1}}={:.0f}$ [unit]'.format(var1[i])
    label2 = r'$q_{{1}}(10)={:.0f}$ [unit]'.format(quant1[i,0])
    ax.plot(var2,quant1[i,:], linestyle='dotted', linewidth=2, color=colors[i])
    ax.plot(var2,quant2[i,:], linestyle='solid', linewidth=1, color=colors[i])
    ax.fill_between(var2,quant1[i,:]-quant1err[i,:],quant1[i,:]+quant1err[i,:], alpha=0.16, color=colors[i])
    ax.fill_between(var2,quant2[i,:]-quant2err[i,:],quant2[i,:]+quant2err[i,:], alpha=0.16, color=colors[i],\
                    label=label1+'\n'+label2)


# finalize figure
ax.set_xlim(np.min(var2),np.max(var2))
ax.set_xlabel('$v_{2}$ [unit]')
ax.set_ylabel('$q_{2}$ [unit]')
plt.tight_layout()
ax.annotate(text=r'$Q_{1}=v_{1}+v_{2}$',
            xy=(0.50,0.77), xycoords='axes fraction',
            xytext=(1.05,0.95), textcoords='axes fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->',connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.2'),
            fontsize=20)
ax.annotate(text=r'$Q_{2}=v_{1}-v_{2}$',
            xy=(0.70,0.35), xycoords='axes fraction',
            xytext=(1.05,0.85), textcoords='axes fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->',connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.1'),
            fontsize=20)
leg = ax.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.475,0.775), labelspacing=1)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

**Output**
[image: output]

Comment: The intent of the question is that you want to combine the legend handler with a filled rectangle and a dotted line or lines?

Comment: Yes, similar to the linked question,, but for multiple sets of data.

Comment: This is the [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ffuTbyHZBptfsgEl1CFYmYIRo3Ut3bj6?usp=sharing) I created with the understanding that the intent of the question is to overlay the legend handle with a rectangle and a line. I've read the comments but still don't understand the intent, so I'm sharing the code for now. If you don't need it, delete it.

Comment: Thanks! This is very close. Although I'm struggling to get the solid line in the legend as well.

Comment: Since we are merging labels, we use handler 1 to handle this. Do I also need to combine lines and rectangles? If so, we can use 10 labels without combining label 2.

Comment: Thanks for the help @r-beginners! One minor issue left: the dotted and solid lines overlap in the legend entries. How could this be changed conveniently?

Comment: Is this a comment on the code in Colab at the moment? I tried to make a rectangle and a dotted line, and a rectangle and a line vertically, and struggled to make them into two horizontal rows, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Yes, I'm struggling with this as well. Right now it seems that both lines overlap. Either way thanks so far!

Comment: I'll leave it up to you to modify the question using my code or to ask a new one. Good luck with solving your problem.

Comment: You promptly posted a new question! Upvote +1