# Added shared error around Pandas line plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot, line-plot

I have a nice looking line plot, but I want to add shaded areas designating the margin of error above and below my existing line. I have a column with the error already calculated in my pandas data frame, but I am unsure how to add it to my plot.

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
joinedDF.plot(x='date', y='count', figsize = (15, 8), ax = ax)
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Count")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the pandas plotting documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#plotting-directly-with-matplotlib), and assuming your DataFrame `joinedDF` has the error in a column named `err`, run this after your current code:

```
plt.fill_between(joinedDF['date'], 
                 joinedDF['count'] - joinedDF['err'], 
                 joinedDF['count'] + joinedDF['err'], 
                 color='b', 
                 alpha=0.2);
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the shaded area to the legend? @Peter Leimbigler

Comment: It is indeed :) I don't have a ready-to-go example, but this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736920/line-plus-shaded-region-for-error-band-in-matplotlibs-legend